# Existence of closed and intersecting geodesics for a classical mechanical system

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry

Consider the configuration space of a double pendulum - it's a torus, $T^2$.

Some well-known theorems say that on such closed manifold there exists at least one (closed) geodetic for *every* closed curves homotopy class, provided the total energy of the system is high enough.

What puzzles me is that such geodesics could in fact intersect *transversally*. Either with themselves, either with one another. Is it right or wrong?

And does this mean that also in phase space such intersection could occur?